# Shift elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

*This question contains its own answer at the bottom. Use preallocated arrays.*

Following-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5859144/478288) years ago, is there a canonical "shift" function in numpy? I don't see anything from [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html).

Here's a simple version of what I'm looking for:

```
def shift(xs, n):
    if n >= 0:
        return np.r_[np.full(n, np.nan), xs[:-n]]
    else:
        return np.r_[xs[-n:], np.full(-n, np.nan)]
```

Using this is like:

```
In [76]: xs
Out[76]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

In [77]: shift(xs, 3)
Out[77]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.])

In [78]: shift(xs, -3)
Out[78]: array([  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

<sub>This question came from my attempt to [write a fast rolling_product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386409/478288) yesterday. I needed a way to "shift" a cumulative product and all I could think of was to replicate the logic in `np.roll()`.</sub>

---

So `np.concatenate()` is much faster than `np.r_[]`. This version of the function performs a lot better:

```
def shift(xs, n):
    if n >= 0:
        return np.concatenate((np.full(n, np.nan), xs[:-n]))
    else:
        return np.concatenate((xs[-n:], np.full(-n, np.nan)))
```

---

An even faster version simply pre-allocates the array:

```
def shift(xs, n):
    e = np.empty_like(xs)
    if n >= 0:
        e[:n] = np.nan
        e[n:] = xs[:-n]
    else:
        e[n:] = np.nan
        e[:n] = xs[-n:]
    return e
```

*The above proposal is the answer. Use preallocated arrays.*

Comment: wondering if `np.r_[np.full(n, np.nan), xs[:-n]]` could be replaced with `np.r_[[np.nan]*n, xs[:-n]]` likewise for other condition, without the need of `np.full`

Comment: @JohnGalt `[np.nan]*n` is plain python and will therefore be slower than `np.full(n, np.nan)`. Not for small `n`, but it will be transformed to numpy array by np.r_ which takes away the advantage.

Comment: @swenzel Just timed it and `[np.nan]*n` is faster than `np.full(n, np.nan)` for `n=[10,1000,10000]`. Need to check if `np.r_` takes a hit.

Comment: If speed is of concern, the array size plays a huge role for the best algorithm (added a benchmark comparison below). Also, nowadays numba.njit can be used to make the shift faster if called repeatedly.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

For those who want to just copy and paste the fastest implementation of shift, there is a benchmark and conclusion(see the end). In addition, I introduce fill_value parameter and fix some bugs.

#### Benchmark

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

# enhanced from IronManMark20 version
def shift1(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    arr = np.roll(arr,num)
    if num < 0:
        arr[num:] = fill_value
    elif num > 0:
        arr[:num] = fill_value
    return arr

# use np.roll and np.put by IronManMark20
def shift2(arr,num):
    arr=np.roll(arr,num)
    if num<0:
         np.put(arr,range(len(arr)+num,len(arr)),np.nan)
    elif num > 0:
         np.put(arr,range(num),np.nan)
    return arr

# use np.pad and slice by me.
def shift3(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    l = len(arr)
    if num < 0:
        arr = np.pad(arr, (0, abs(num)), mode='constant', constant_values=(fill_value,))[:-num]
    elif num > 0:
        arr = np.pad(arr, (num, 0), mode='constant', constant_values=(fill_value,))[:-num]

    return arr

# use np.concatenate and np.full by chrisaycock
def shift4(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    if num >= 0:
        return np.concatenate((np.full(num, fill_value), arr[:-num]))
    else:
        return np.concatenate((arr[-num:], np.full(-num, fill_value)))

# preallocate empty array and assign slice by chrisaycock
def shift5(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    if num > 0:
        result[:num] = fill_value
        result[num:] = arr[:-num]
    elif num < 0:
        result[num:] = fill_value
        result[:num] = arr[-num:]
    else:
        result[:] = arr
    return result

arr = np.arange(2000).astype(float)

def benchmark_shift1():
    shift1(arr, 3)

def benchmark_shift2():
    shift2(arr, 3)

def benchmark_shift3():
    shift3(arr, 3)

def benchmark_shift4():
    shift4(arr, 3)

def benchmark_shift5():
    shift5(arr, 3)

benchmark_set = ['benchmark_shift1', 'benchmark_shift2', 'benchmark_shift3', 'benchmark_shift4', 'benchmark_shift5']

for x in benchmark_set:
    number = 10000
    t = timeit.timeit('%s()' % x, 'from __main__ import %s' % x, number=number)
    print '%s time: %f' % (x, t)
```

benchmark result:

```
benchmark_shift1 time: 0.265238
benchmark_shift2 time: 0.285175
benchmark_shift3 time: 0.473890
benchmark_shift4 time: 0.099049
benchmark_shift5 time: 0.052836
```

#### Conclusion

shift5 is winner! It's OP's third solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comparisons. Any idea what is the fastest way to do it without using a new array?

Comment: In the last clause of `shift5` it's better to write `result[:] = arr` instead of `result = arr`, to keep function behavior consistent.

Comment: This should be chosed as an answer

Comment: @avysk comment is pretty important - please update the shift5 method.
Functions that sometimes return a copy and sometimes return a reference are the path to hell.

Comment: Updated: use `result[:] = arr` instead of `result = arr` in order to keep consistence.

Comment: @gzx, I haven't checked all of the suggestions, but for`shift5`, I ended up adding `arr = arr.astype(float)`. I tried the function with an array on integers but got `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: @Josmoor98 That's because `type(np.NAN) is float`. If you shift integer array using these functions, you need to specify a integer fill_value.

Answer (score 134):

Not numpy but scipy provides exactly the shift functionality you want,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import shift

xs = np.array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

shift(xs, 3, cval=np.NaN)
```

where default is to bring in a constant value from outside the array with value `cval`, set here to `nan`. This gives the desired output,

```
array([ nan, nan, nan, 0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])
```

and the negative shift works similarly,

```
shift(xs, -3, cval=np.NaN)
```

Provides output

```
array([  3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Comment: The scipy shift function is REALLY slow.  I rolled my own using np.concatenate and it was much faster.

Comment: numpy.roll is faster. pandas also uses it. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/internals.py#L1044

Comment: Just tested the scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift (scipy 1.4.1) against all the other alternatives listed on this page (see my answer below), and this is the ***slowest*** possible solution. Use only if speed is of no importance in your application.

Comment: `from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift` was deprecated.  Now, simply use `from scipy.ndimage import shift`

Comment: One nice feature about interpolation.shift though is that it supports multidimensional arrays. For a 2D array, you would need to do shift(xs, (3,0), cval=np.NaN) instead of just 3 as in 1D.

Answer (score 30):

## Benchmarks & introducing Numba

### 1. Summary

- The accepted answer (`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift`) is the *slowest* solution listed in this page.
- [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (@numba.njit) gives some performance boost when array size smaller than ~25.000
- "Any method" equally good when array size large (>250.000).
- The fastest option really depends on 
      (1)  Length of your arrays
      (2)  Amount of shift you need to do.
- Below is the picture of the timings of all different methods listed on this page (2020-07-11), using constant shift = 10. As one can see, with small array sizes some methods are use more than +2000% time than the best method.

[image: Relative timings, constant shift (10), all methods]

### 2. Detailed benchmarks with the best options

- Choose `shift4_numba` (defined below) if you want good all-arounder

[image: Relative timings, best methods (Benchmarks)]

### 3. Code

#### 3.1 `shift4_numba`

- Good all-arounder; max 20% wrt. to the best method with any array size
- Best method with medium array sizes: ~ 500 < N < 20.000.
- Caveat: Numba jit (just in time compiler) will give performance boost only if you are calling the decorated function more than once. The first call takes usually 3-4 times longer than the subsequent calls. You can get even more performance boost with [ahead of time compiled numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html).

```py
import numba

@numba.njit
def shift4_numba(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    if num >= 0:
        return np.concatenate((np.full(num, fill_value), arr[:-num]))
    else:
        return np.concatenate((arr[-num:], np.full(-num, fill_value)))
```

#### 3.2. `shift5_numba`

- Best option with small (N <= 300.. 1500) array sizes. Treshold depends on needed amount of shift.
- Good performance on any array size; max + 50% compared to the fastest solution.
- Caveat: Numba jit (just in time compiler) will give performance boost only if you are calling the decorated function more than once. The first call takes usually 3-4 times longer than the subsequent calls. You can get even more performance boost with [ahead of time compiled numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html).

```py
import numba

@numba.njit
def shift5_numba(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    if num > 0:
        result[:num] = fill_value
        result[num:] = arr[:-num]
    elif num < 0:
        result[num:] = fill_value
        result[:num] = arr[-num:]
    else:
        result[:] = arr
    return result
```

#### 3.3. `shift5`

- Best method with array sizes ~ 20.000 < N < 250.000
- Same as `shift5_numba`, just remove the @numba.njit decorator.

## 4 Appendix

### 4.1 Details about used methods

- `shift_scipy`: `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift` (scipy 1.4.1) - The option from accepted answer, which is *clearly the slowest alternative*.
- `shift1`: `np.roll` and `out[:num] xnp.nan` by [IronManMark20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799589/ironmanmark20) & [gzc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090791/gzc)
- `shift2`: `np.roll` and `np.put` by [IronManMark20](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799589/ironmanmark20)
- `shift3`: `np.pad` and `slice` by  [gzc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090791/gzc)
- `shift4`: `np.concatenate` and `np.full` by  [chrisaycock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478288/chrisaycock)
- `shift5`: using two times `result[slice] = x` by  [chrisaycock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478288/chrisaycock)
- `shift#_numba`: @[numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).njit decorated versions of the previous.

*The `shift2` and `shift3` contained functions that were not supported by the current numba (0.50.1).*

### 4.2 Other test results

#### 4.2.1 Relative timings, all methods

- [Relative timings, 10% shift, all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBD4J.png)
- [Relative timings, constant shift (10), all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUTEO.png)

#### 4.2.2 Raw timings, all methods

- [Raw timings, constant shift (10), all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75QeR.png)
- [Raw timings, 10% shift, all methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVXSc.png)

### 4.2.3 Raw timings, few best methods

- [Raw timings with small arrays, constant shift (10), few best methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C2Rv.png)
- [Raw timings with small arrays, 10% shift, few best methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cETYt.png)
- [Raw timings with large arrays, constant shift (10), few best methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69oJd.png)
- [Raw timings with large arrays, 10% shift, few best methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bxik.png)

Answer (score 11):

There is no single function that does what you want. Your definition of shift is slightly different than what most people are doing. The ways to shift an array are more commonly looped:

```
>>>xs=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>>shift(xs,3)
array([3,4,5,1,2])
```

However, you can do what you want with two functions.
 Consider `a=np.array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])`:

```
def shift2(arr,num):
    arr=np.roll(arr,num)
    if num<0:
         np.put(arr,range(len(arr)+num,len(arr)),np.nan)
    elif num > 0:
         np.put(arr,range(num),np.nan)
    return arr
>>>shift2(a,3)
[ nan  nan  nan   0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.]
>>>shift2(a,-3)
[  3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  nan  nan  nan]
```

After running cProfile on your given function and the above code you provided, I found that the code you provided makes 42 function calls while `shift2` made 14 calls when arr is positive and 16 when it is negative. <strike>I will be experimenting with timing to see how each performs with real data.</strike>

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look at this. I know about `np.roll()`; I used the technique in the links in my question. As for your implementation, any chance you can get your function to work for negative shift values?

Comment: Interestingly, `np.concatenate()` is a lot faster than `np.r_[]`. The former is what `np.roll()` uses, after all.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert `ndarray` to `Series` or `DataFrame` with `pandas` first, then you can use `shift` method as you want.

Example:

```
In [1]: from pandas import Series

In [2]: data = np.arange(10)

In [3]: data
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: data = Series(data)

In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64

In [6]: data = data.shift(3)

In [7]: data
Out[7]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    5.0
9    6.0
dtype: float64

In [8]: data = data.values

In [9]: data
Out[9]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this with Pandas:

Using a 2356-long array:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([...])
```

**Using scipy:**

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

%timeit shift(xs, 1, cval=np.nan)
# 956 µs ± 77.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Using Pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd

%timeit pd.Series(xs).shift(1).values
# 377 µs ± 9.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In this example, using Pandas was about ~8 times faster than Scipy

Comment: The fastest method is the pre-allocation that I posted at the end of my question. Your `Series` technique took 146 us on my computer, whereas my approach took under 4 us.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-liner from numpy and aren't too concerned about performance, try:

```
np.sum(np.diag(the_array,1),0)[:-1]
```

Explanation: `np.diag(the_array,1)` creates a matrix with your array one-off the diagonal, `np.sum(...,0)` sums the matrix column-wise, and `...[:-1]` takes the elements that would correspond to the size of the original array.  Playing around with the `1` and `:-1` as parameters can give you shifts in different directions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `np.roll` is what you need

```
arr = np.arange(10)
shift = 2  # shift length
arr_1 = np.roll(arr, shift=shift)
arr_1[:shift] = np.nan
```

Comment: I answered my own question. See the last version that pre-allocates the array. Also, `np.roll` is already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30401705/478288).

Answer (score 2):

A simple and effective way supporting **numba** and negative shift values like **Pandas** library. It **prevents** **corrupting** the original array in arguments, and also works with an **integer** array:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba_shift(arr_: np.ndarray, shift: np.int32 = 1) -> np.ndarray:
    arr = arr_.copy().astype(np.float64)
    if shift > 0:
        arr[shift:] = arr[:-shift]
        arr[:shift] = np.nan
    else:
        arr[:shift] = arr[-shift:]
        arr[shift:] = np.nan
    return arr
```

**Example**:

```
ar = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
numba_shift(ar,-1)

    array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6., nan])
```

**Timeit**:

```
%timeit numba_shift(ar,-1)

1.02 µs ± 9.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Note**: if you dont need numba, just with numpy, then delete the line `@njit` and the numba import.

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves `np.roll` and masked arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma # this is for masked array

def shift(arr, shift):
    r_arr = np.roll(arr, shift=shift)
    m_arr = ma.masked_array(r_arr,dtype=float)
    if shift > 0: m_arr[:shift] = ma.masked
    else: m_arr[shift:] = ma.masked
    return m_arr.filled(np.nan)
```

Basically, I just use `np.roll` to shift the array, then use `ma.masked_array` to mark the unwanted elements as invalid, and fill those invalid positions with `np.nan`. I set the `dtype` to `float` so that filling with `np.nan` wouldn't cause any problems.

```
In [11]: shift(arr, 3)
Out[11]: array([nan, nan, nan,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])

In [12]: shift(arr, -3)
Out[12]: array([ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., nan, nan, nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalization of the fast answer (`shift5`) to support arbitrary multidimensional arrays:

```
def shift(array, offset, constant_values=0):
  """Returns copy of array shifted by offset, with fill using constant."""
  array = np.asarray(array)
  offset = np.atleast_1d(offset)
  assert len(offset) == array.ndim
  new_array = np.empty_like(array)

  def slice1(o):
    return slice(o, None) if o >= 0 else slice(0, o)

  new_array[tuple(slice1(o) for o in offset)] = (
      array[tuple(slice1(-o) for o in offset)])

  for axis, o in enumerate(offset):
    new_array[(slice(None),) * axis +
              (slice(0, o) if o >= 0 else slice(o, None),)] = constant_values

  return new_array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for two dimensions that's not using special built-in-functions from numpy and thus is compatible with numba.

```
def shift(array, dy, dx):
    n, m = array.shape[:2]
    e = np.zeros((n, m))
    if dy > 0 and dx > 0:
        e[dy:, dx:] = array[:-dy, :-dx]
        return e
    elif dy > 0 and dx < 0:
        e[dy:, :dx] = array[:-dy, -dx:]
        return e
    elif dy < 0 and dx > 0:
        e[:dy, dx:] = array[-dy:, :-dx]
        return e
    elif dy < 0 and dx < 0:
        e[:dy, :dx] = array[-dy:, -dx:]
        return e
    elif dy < 0 and dx == 0:
        e[:dy, :] = array[-dy:, :]
        return e
    elif dy > 0 and dx == 0:
        e[dy:, :] = array[:-dy, :]
        return e
    elif dy == 0 and dx < 0:
        e[:, :dx] = array[:, -dx:]
        return e
    elif dy == 0 and dx > 0:
        e[:, dx:] = array[:, :-dx]
        return e
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I have a quicker solution: why don't just use deque ?
I added 2 benchmark to the benchmarked solution from @gzc:

```
def shift6(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    for _ in range(num):
        darr.appendleft(fill_value)

def shift7(arr, num, fill_value=np.nan):
    darr = deque(arr)
    for _ in range(num):
        darr.appendleft(fill_value)

darr = deque(arr)

def benchmark_shift6():
    shift6(arr, 3)
    
def benchmark_shift7():
    shift6(arr, 3)

benchmark_set = ['benchmark_shift1', 'benchmark_shift2', 'benchmark_shift3', 'benchmark_shift4', 'benchmark_shift5', 'benchmark_shift6', 'benchmark_shift7']
```

And on my laptop the output is a lot of better than any other solutions proposed:

```
%s time: ('benchmark_shift1', 0.08232757700170623) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift2', 0.0934765400015749) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift3', 0.14349375600431813) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift4', 0.03575193700089585) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift5', 0.01389261399890529) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift6', 0.0025887360025080852) 
%s time: ('benchmark_shift7', 0.0024806019937386736)
```

Comment: There is a fatal error in your code. Your `benchmark_shift7()` calls `shift6()` when it is supposed to call `shift7()`. Correcting this shows that using a deque by far the slowest operation. Also, your `benchmark_shift6()` isn't believable because it creates the deque outside of the benchmark!

Comment: You're right about the benchmark for the test with deque creation: my mistake. Also if deque are chosen by design and it doesn't need the conversion , it's the fastest solution of all proposed answer ! Try to be creative when you code :)

Comment: The question is literally about numpy arrays. "Use something completely unlike numpy arrays" is not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

One way to do it without spilt the code into cases

with array:

```
def shift(arr, dx, default_value):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    get_neg_or_none = lambda s: s if s < 0 else None
    get_pos_or_none = lambda s: s if s > 0 else None
    result[get_neg_or_none(dx): get_pos_or_none(dx)] = default_value
    result[get_pos_or_none(dx): get_neg_or_none(dx)] = arr[get_pos_or_none(-dx): get_neg_or_none(-dx)]     
    return result
```

with matrix it can be done like this:

```
def shift(image, dx, dy, default_value):
    res = np.full_like(image, default_value)

    get_neg_or_none = lambda s: s if s < 0 else None
    get_pos_or_none = lambda s : s if s > 0 else None

    res[get_pos_or_none(-dy): get_neg_or_none(-dy), get_pos_or_none(-dx): get_neg_or_none(-dx)] = \
        image[get_pos_or_none(dy): get_neg_or_none(dy), get_pos_or_none(dx): get_neg_or_none(dx)]
    return res
```

Comment: This is neither clean nor fast.