# Writing similar pandas function on numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

When I am using pandas dataframe, I usually need to do this operation:

```
x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())
```

However, I need to work with arrays, and perform this same function.

I noticed that:

```
x.eq(0).sum()
```

Can be written like this in numpy:

```
np.count_nonzero(x == 0)
```

This second part `((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())`, I don't know which numpy function substitutes `shift()`.

How to write this function `((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())` on numpy ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399534/shift-elements-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

The shift idea comes from [Shift elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399534/shift-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

x.eq(0) -> x==0
x.shift() -> shift(x, 1, cval=1)
x.ne(0) -> x!=0
```

And thus:

```
((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum()) -> np.sum(np.logical_and((x==0),shift(x, 1, cval=np.nan)!=0))
```

Finally:

```
x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum()) -> np.count_nonzero(x == 0)/np.sum(np.logical_and((x==0),shift(x, 1, cval=1)!=0))
```

But if I where you, I would just do:

```
x = pd.Series(x)
```