# How can I put multiple images inside an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy-ndarray

My image is a ndarray(2048, 2048, 3). I'd like to modify it and keep a copy (around 5) of the former version so I can reverse any modification done via click event.

In the code bellow, I am drawing circle for every click on the image. However, I'd like to store more than one image and remove the last one (`pop()`) for each right click.

```
click_pts = []
def click(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global click_pts, image, image_ref
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        click_pts.append((x, y))
        image_ref = np.ndarray.copy(image)
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        print((x, y))
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        click_pts.pop()
        image = np.ndarray.copy(image_ref)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)


image = cv2.imread('images/RT1_2th.png')
image_ref = np.ndarray.copy(image)
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click)
# Loop until 'q' is pressed
while True:
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I failed to find any reliable way to store multiple image in an array... doesn't matter what type of array it is, but having `.pop()` function would be great.

Also, (side note), in the [OpenCV example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d5b/tutorial_py_mouse_handling.html), `image` is not passed into the function and a click results in (if I remove `global image` from `click`):

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment
```

I don't really like global variable, I wonder, what is the alternative?
**Edit:**
Added two functions handle the shifting. The lshift shifts to left and replace last image with a new one:

```
def lshift(arr, new_arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    result[:-1] = arr[1:]
    result[-1] = new_arr
    return result


def rshift(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    result[1:] = arr[:-1]
    result[0] = arr[0]
    return result
```

It works pretty well but don't forget to use `np.array.copy()` to pass by value the image that is drawn upon. Otherwise, it is passed by reference and you end up with the same copy of everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a NumPy array of zeros.

```
arr = np.zeros((5,2048,2048,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Now you can easily add your images to and get anyone you want. Suppose you want the last one then `arr[4]` should suffice.

Comment: How would you shift the [1:] arrays to [:-1], i.e. get rid of the first one and add a new one at the end?

Comment: Edited the post with working code. I was inspired by this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399534/shift-elements-in-a-numpy-array