# How to plot two lists of data with various length in Python (embedding of a time-series in phase space)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My aim is to transform a one-dimensional time-series into a two-dimensional phase space. Since the time-series is one-dimensional, the phase space will be a pseudo (lag) phase space.

One theoretical approach to transform a time-series into pseudo phase space is as follows:

1. The original list of data is the full-length time-series x(t).
2. A subseries of data is the "lagged" version of the original time-series, starting with the second value of the time-series (instead of with its first one, as the original time-series) x(t+1).

Consequently, the subseries will always have one value less in its list. For a 3D phase space, a second subseries would have two values less in its list.
This is where my code related problem comes in, since matplotlib does not allow me to plot a two-dimensional plane when the length of two lists is not equal.

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example time-series
Data = [924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4, 1, 2, 3]

# Embedding (time-series to phase space)
x_list = Data[:-1]
y_list = Data[1:]

# Plot
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, c="blue", linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This code uses the whole length of the time-series except the last value in the list by `x_list = Data[:-1]` for the x-axis. For the y-axis, the code uses the whole time-series except the very first item in the list by `Data[1:]`.

While this code works, its result is not a real embedding of a time-series into its two-dimensional phase space, since `x_list = Data[:-1]` does not include the last value of the time-series.

What would be a proper way for coding and plotting the phase space of subseries that increasingly diminish in length compared to the original time-series data?

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and it's [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) method:

```
Data = [924, -5, 24, 1, 0, 242, -5, 42, 5, 1, -9, 50, 3, 432, 0, -5, 4, 1, 2, 3]

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timeseries = pd.Series(Data)

plt.plot(timeseries, timeseries.shift(), c='blue', linewidth=0.5)
```

For a lag of 2 use `shift(2)`

output:

[image: shifted Series]

*NB. you can also [shift with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399534/shift-elements-in-a-numpy-array), but it is less elegant IMO*

###### autocorrelation

I am not sure what is your end goal, but in case you try to determine if you have a period, or to perform autocorrelation analysis you can use [`pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot.html):

```
pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(timeseries)
```

output:

[image: autocorrelation]

Comment: is there a difference between `x = Data; y = x[1:]+[x[0]]` and padas .shift() ? Seems to me that is a big import to get rid of 2 lines of code?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the generalization, it seems that OP wants to apply this to potentially many dimensions. Also I suspect a broader end goal (maybe autocorrelation analysis?), thus the second part of my answer. Otherwise, I don't know why OP asks the question…

Comment: Currently, my aim is only the correct embedding of a time-series (e.g., a list of datapoints) into phase space in Python. Further analyses steps surely come later, though.

Answer (score 1):

For a wrap around solution you could use a list comp to shift the data:

```
Data = list(range(10))

d = 5
multi = [Data[dims:]+Data[:dims] for dims in range(d) ]

print(*multi, sep="\n")

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

if you do not want to wrap around, fix it like so:

```
d = 5
multi = [(Data[dims:]+Data[:dims])[:-d+1] for dims in range(d)]
```

to get

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you want a *hypothetical* last value you would have to do some extrapolation of the series you got - if that makes more sense then cutting it short ... dunno.

Comment: Hello Patrick. As I understand your code, it starts each subseries using x(t+n). This shift is correct. However, the subseries are not decreasing in length; instead, the length of each subseries is equal to the length of the original time-series (list). Adding new numeric values to each additional list has to be avoided. Extrapolation is therefore not needed.